# Kendo Datasource not sending string to Controller

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-datasource

I am creating a CRUD application, My application is getting a string from from a Kendo input box, and will need to send it to my controller which is expecting a string that I am getting from my Jquery call.  However, the string is not getting to my controller.  I have tried various ways and I am not able to send it through my Transport.  I have put break point and I can confirm that the value is being picked up in my Kendo Observable.

My Datasource

```
   var client = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {               
            url: "Client/SearchClient",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
        },
```

My Controller

```
        public ActionResult SearchClient()
        {
        return View();
        }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SearchClient(string name)
    {
        Repo repo = new Repo();
        var result = repo.GetClient();

        return Json(new
        {
            list = result,
            count = result.Count
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

This is my Kendo Observable

```
 var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    client: {
        clientName: "",
        clientNumber: "",
        clientType: "",
    },
    dropdownlist: ["HCC", "Tax", "Audit", "Advisory"],

    create: function (e) {
        var userRequest = $("#clientname").val();
        if (userRequest) {
            client.read(userRequest);
        }
        if (!userRequest)
        alert("Please Enter Client Name")
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search Client method wants POST, not GET? The default will be GET. Either change your api method to use HttpGet, or change the transport to method: "post" for read.

```
var client = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {               
            url: "Client/SearchClient",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            method: "post"
        },
```